# Request to the fuseki server and create a new dataset through python

Tags: python, httprequest, sparql, fuseki

i'm doing a project in python where I need to make an http request to the fuseki server to create a new dataset. Can anyone help me?

my fuseki server is like this:
[image]

and i wanna make a http request or a sparql request from python, to add a new dataset

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: the only API like way is via HTTP: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-server-protocol.html#datasets-and-services